# PowerShell sort string array, where each element consists of two fields, by the second field

Tags: arrays, sorting, powershell

I have an array filled with strings like these (SHA256 checksums and relative paths delimited with a semicolon):

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855;./zzz.txt
d0c4c3e65c450251e44ec41c3c6ee0ea456d02bd74f041c9299934176ec325e6;./kkk.xlsx
9a1d469cdc7c2072b19a7e483a818c5e4e9de070298c60b34de29930e7b79209;./árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép/kkk - Shortcut.lnk
```

And I'd like to sort these rows by the second column. So the sorted array should look like this:

```
9a1d469cdc7c2072b19a7e483a818c5e4e9de070298c60b34de29930e7b79209;./árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép/kkk - Shortcut.lnk
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855;./zzz.txt
d0c4c3e65c450251e44ec41c3c6ee0ea456d02bd74f041c9299934176ec325e6;./kkk.xlsx
```

There are no headers and stuff, the only thing is the semicolon (`;`) character which delimites the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Array in a variable:

```
  $a | sort  {$_  -replace  "(.*;\./)", ''}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the content to csv format, parse the content by semicolon delimiter, add headers and sort the output by the Path property:

```
@"
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855;./zzz.txt
d0c4c3e65c450251e44ec41c3c6ee0ea456d02bd74f041c9299934176ec325e6;./kkk.xlsx
9a1d469cdc7c2072b19a7e483a818c5e4e9de070298c60b34de29930e7b79209;./árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép/kkk - Shortcut.lnk
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Checksum,Path -Delimiter ';' | Sort-Object Path


Checksum                                                                   Path                                                                      
--------                                                                   ----                                                                      
9a1d469cdc7c2072b19a7e483a818c5e4e9de070298c60b34de29930e7b79209           ./árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép/kkk - Shortcut.lnk                               
d0c4c3e65c450251e44ec41c3c6ee0ea456d02bd74f041c9299934176ec325e6           ./kkk.xlsx                                                                
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855           ./zzz.txt
```